# Using JsConfig.BeginScope with Async Client Methods in ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack

I'm trying to set an option on JsConfig for a single async method on JsonServiceClient by using JsConfigScope, but it does not seem to work. What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to do this?

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);
using (var scope = JsConfig.BeginScope())
{
  scope.EmitCamelCaseNames = true;
  return client.PostAsync<SomeResponse>(url, request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a using scope with an async request since the scope will be disposed before the async service has completed. You would need to await the response, i.e:

```
using (JsConfig.With(new Config { TextCase = TextCase.CamelCase }))
{
    return await client.PostAsync<SomeResponse>(url, request);
}
```

You can use the lower-level [HTTP Utils](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Http-Utils) to split the request serialization and response deserialization outside of the async call which is the [approach used in the StripeGateway](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Stripe/blob/35ca6324d83df6cb5578c2ea861a597719940b19/src/Stripe/StripeGateway.cs#L560-L578).

Otherwise you could potentially use the Response filter to dispose of the scoped configuration, e.g:

```
var scope = JsConfig.With(new Config { TextCase = TextCase.CamelCase });
var client = new JsonServiceClient(BaseUrl) {
    ResponseFilter = httpRes => scope.Dispose()
};
return client.PostAsync<SomeResponse>(url, request);
```